# Parsing a little endian hex string to decimal

Tags: javascript, hex, endianness

I have an little endian hex string that needs to be converted to a decimal in JavaScript.

Example hex string: "12AB34CD"
To get the correct value it need to swap the bytes to this: "CD34AB12"

Currently I just swap the bytes using substring and then use parseInt().

```
var string = "12AB34CD";
var parsedInt = parseInt("0x" + string.substring(6,8) + string.substring(4,6)+ string.substring(2,4) + string.substring(0,2);
```

I have lots of data with unknown lenght to parse, so I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What would you call "simpler" or "easier"? I'd make only a minor change, but that is only a "I'd perfer it that way" thing: `parseInt(string.substr(6,2) + string.substr(4,2) + string.substr(2,2) + string.substr(0,2), 16);`

Comment: @Thomas well I have a lot of different  hex string with different lengths, doing this every time is kind of a drag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use something like this to swap the bytes:

```js
var endian = "12AB34CD";

var r = parseInt('0x'+endian.match(/../g).reverse().join(''));

console.log(r); // Decimal
console.log(r.toString(16).toUpperCase());  // Hex
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this myself but the accepted answer is much shorter.

```js
var hexstring = "12AB34CD";

function littleEndianHexStringToDecimal(string)
{
    if(!string) return undefined;
    var len = string.length;
    var bigEndianHexString = "0x";
    for(var i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        bigEndianHexString += string.substring((len-((i+1)*2)),(len-(i*2)));
    }
    return parseInt(bigEndianHexString);
}

console.log(littleEndianHexStringToDecimal(hexstring));
```